# How to generate skeleton using cucumber feature file

Tags: jasmine, protractor, cucumber

We have tried below steps:

1. on node command prompt we tried exciting below commands

   > Npm install -g cucumber
   >   Also we tried
   >   npm install -g protractor-cucumber
2. > cucumber --version

Above command opening webstorm editor.

3. We have created feature file(feature/testfeature.feature)
4. Now to generate skeleton we tried running below command on cmd prompt.

> Cucumber.js
>   It is opening webstorm editor

5. We are not able to see skeleton file

Could you please suggest if we are missing anything
We should be able to create skeleton file using npm command.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to generate `Step definitions` structure/skeleton in your console you have to run the protractor command

> protractor your_conf.js

your **conf.js** should look like this -

```
exports.config = {

directConnect: true,
baseUrl: '',
capabilities: {
'browserName':
    (process.env.TEST_BROWSER_NAME || 'firefox'),
'version':
    (process.env.TEST_BROWSER_VERSION || 'ANY')
 },

onPrepare: function () {
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
global.expect = chai.expect;
browser.manage().window().maximize();
},

setDefaultTimeout : 60 * 1000,
framework: 'custom',
frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
specs: [
'../Features/*.feature'
 ],

cucumberOpts: {
monochrome: true,
strict: true,
plugin: ["pretty"],
require: ['../StepDefinitions/*.js', '../Support/*.js']
}
};
```