# generating skeleton using Cucumber protractor integration

Tags: protractor, cucumber

I am trying to generate Step defination skeleton by running protractor conf.js file.
I need to implement BDD in Protractor.

**conf.js**

```
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  framework: 'custom',
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
  specs: ['features /*.feature'],
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

**feature file**

```
@tag1
Feature: Add Numbers
  As a user of the calculator
  I want to add 2 numbers

  @tag2
  Scenario: Add 2 small numbers
    Given the calculator is cleared
    When I add 5 and 6
    Then the result should be 11
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console output?

Comment: what is the error? whats the question?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38605648/how-to-generate-skeleton-using-cucumber-feature-file

Answer (score 0):

You have to format tour feature file text as below. Then if you run your conf.js file, you'll see the steps.

@tag1

Feature: Add Numbers As a user of the calculator I want to add 2 numbers

@tag2

Scenario: Add 2 small numbers

```
Given the calculator is cleared
When I add 5 and 6
Then the result should be 11
```